# PHP - Display output from bottom of file

Tags: php

```
<?php

$file = 'C:\wamp\www\Killboard\EPChernarus1\PhitLog.txt';
$searchfor = 'Chernarus';
header('Content-Type: text/html');
$contents = file_get_contents($file);
$contents = str_replace("(ArmA-AH.net)", "(DayZNorway.com)", $contents);
$pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');
$contents = str_replace("DayZ Instance: 11", " Map: Chernarus ", $contents);
$pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*$/m";
$contents = str_replace("PKILL", "Player Killed", $contents);
$contents = str_replace("CLOG", "Combat Logged", $contents);

if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){
   echo "<strong>";
   echo "<div style ='font:11px/21px Arial,tahoma,sans-serif;color:#2983CB'>Killboard Epoch Chernarus: <br>";
   echo '', implode(" <br>", $matches[0]);
   echo "</strong>";
}
else 
{
   echo "No kills yet. Looks like everyone is playing nice.";
}

?>
```

How can I get this to display the lines from bottom of file first?
I'm guessing some sort of array reverse but I couldnt make that work.

Can someone show me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
echo '', implode(" <br>", $matches[0]);
```

to

```
echo '', implode(" <br>", array_reverse($matches[0]));
```

Comment: Yay works perfectly! Thank you very much! One more question tho, as you can see i used the str_replace a few times, can that be done in a neater way or is that just the way to do it?

Comment: you can gather all those strings for replacement in one array and new strings in another array and do it in one str_replace function - remember that in both arrays those corresponding searches and replaces have to have the same keys. Look at the definition of str_replace in manual. BTW, if you accept my answer, please click accepted, thank you :)

Comment: Could you show me how to do that? Im trying but failing. Ill add accept on the answer, thanks so much :)

Comment: $old = array("(ArmA-AH.net)", "DayZ Instance: 11", ....); $new = ("(DayZNorway.com)", " Map: Chernarus ",....); $contents = str_replace($old, $new, $contents);

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in C:\wamp\www\Killboard\OPLingor1\killfeed.php on line 9 ... Getting this now. file now looks like this:  $old = array("(ArmA-AH.net)", "DayZ Instance: 7", "PKILL", "CLOG"); 
 $new = ("(DayZNorway.com)", "Map: Lingor Island", "Player Killed", "Combat Logged"); 
 $contents = str_replace($old, $new, $contents)

Comment: ... and I hope you will still click accept my answer as well  :)

Comment: Sorry, i must be blind. Where do i do that? :p

Comment: On the left at the start of answer, where there is number of upvotes and two arrows to upvote and downvote. There is also place to click that the answer is accepted and then big green V sign comes up. Only the asking user can click that accept, and everybody including asking person can vote up and down.